# HTML page importing XML with XSLT

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I have an HTML page and i want to add it a little content in a DIV using XML and XSLT, how can I import XML and evaluate the relative XSLT?

I have already tried iframe, but it must be resized to fit the content, I try also to use the script shown in this page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757854%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

but i think it is only for IE, which is the best way to operate?

Comment: So you want to load XML data into an already existing HTML page?

Comment: Can you post some of your HTML / XML so we can get a better idea of what you want?

Comment: if you look at the link you will get the idea, it shows my problem but gives a solution browser dependent

Comment: What is the purpose of the xslt? You can put the xml right inside html and use css to style it. Even use display to format as tables and such.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to w3c to supply a browser independent code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(filename)
{
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  }
else
  {
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
try {xhttp.responseType = "msxml-document"} catch(err) {} // Helping IE11
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function displayResult()
{
xml = loadXMLDoc("cdcatalog.xml");
xsl = loadXMLDoc("cdcatalog.xsl");
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document")
  {
  ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
  document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = ex;
  }
// code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
  {
  xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
  resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
  document.getElementById("example").appendChild(resultDocument);
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="displayResult()">
<div id="example" />
</body>
</html>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp